# Finding all permutations of 9 characters

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm having a little problem with this function.

```
def check_possible(input): 
    possibilities = []
    solutions = []


    dict = dictionary(input)
    dict.get_dict()

    words = dict.get_all_words()

    for L in range(0, len(input)+1):
        for subset in itertools.permutations(input, L):
                possibilities.append(subset)


    for possibility in possibilities: 
        poss = "".join(possibility)
        if len(poss) > 3 and len(poss) < 9: 
            for item in words: 
                for i in item:
                    if poss in i:
                        solutions.append(poss)
    return solutions
```

Basically, it takes a list with 9 characters as parameter, and produces a list of all available permutations that are between 3 and 9 characters and are in dictionary (uses 26 dictionary files, 1 for each letter, creates a sublist for each letter given in list, then check for every permutation generated by above function).

So this function should return:

```
>>input = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']
<<['dace', ..., 'face', 'decaf', 'bedad', 'ceded', 'faded', 'faced', 'beaded', 'deface', 'decade', 'defaced']
```

While this works, and it returns the right values, it takes between 10 - 15 minutes to complete. I'm wondering if there's a way of achieving the same result but in less time (preferably, within a minute).

Comment: What does `return` do when not inside a function?

Comment: My apologies, it was supposed to be in a function.

Comment: Maybe [itertools.permutations()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) can do the work for you. DRY!

Comment: Using itertools.permutations you could do something like this it should improve performance :) https://repl.it/FhQo/0

Answer (score 1):

Your current runtime complexity is that for each generated word from the letters, you check the whole dictionary in linear time to try to find it. This gets really slow as the size of the dictionary grows. So your complexity is `O(K * D)`, where `K` is the number of subsets generated, and `D` is the size of the dictionary.

One thing that you could optimize is looking up the words in the dictionary. You could save the dictionary in a python `set`, which supports constant time lookup for any element. This improves your complexity to `O(D)` for constructing the set, and `O(K)` for checking the words. This leads to a complexity of `O(D + K)` overall, which is far better than `O(D * K)` and will probably run in seconds rather than minutes.

Comment: It takes 15 minutes to generate the permutations of the characters, the comparing part is relatively fast (a couple seconds). I hope I understood your answer correctly.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The number of permutations are (9! + 8! + 7! + ..), these are around 500k, and should generate in a few seconds. In fact I tried your first for loop and it runs in only a second on my machine.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I have now seen my error. Tomorrow I will rework the function to use sets. Should I use any special comparing method, to make it faster or just plain "for item in permutations: if item in dictionarySet: print(item)"? I apologize, I'm still a beginner, so I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: I think the plain `if item in dict` should work. Good luck reworking your function, and please repost here if you found more difficulties.